# Remap an JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remap an JS Array. Something like this

```
var data = [
    {
        description: "bla",
        value: 234,
    }
    {
        description: "bla",
        value: 234,
    },
    {
        description: "bla",
        value: 234,
    },
    {
        description: "bla",
        value: 234,
    },
    {
        description: "bla",
        value: 234,
    }, 
]
```

should be remapped to 2 single arrays. One array (`descriptions`) should contain all description values and the other array (`values`) should contain all the value values.

I think there was a builtin method for this in JavaScript, but I don't know how it is named.

Comment: It is [___`Array#map`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Map returns a single value. You want forEach. But it's simple iteration and collection-should be easily searchable.

Comment: @Rayon maybe easier with `foreach`, since you need two arrays.

Comment: Array.map will require 2 iterations of the array. reduce will only require one.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"should be remapped to 2 single arrays. One array (descriptions) should contain all description values and the other array (values) should contain all the value values."*

Here's your desired solution:

```js
var data = [{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234}],
    descriptions = [],
    values = [];

    data.forEach(function(v){
      descriptions.push(v.description);
      values.push(v.value);
    })

    console.log(descriptions);
    console.log(values);
```

Comment: This is a good solution, and probably more suited to what author wanted but why `forEach` normal for would be more efficient.

Comment: @MaciejKozieja Your solution is good aswell, but that's not the point. The point is that OP didn't precise his desired output and it just caused conflicts in answers. Argh.

Comment: @Kinduser I know but you know that sometimes words don't tell everything and if you are begginer you don't think about meny thigs

Comment: @YannikBürkle Consider upvoting (:

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```js
var data = [{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234},{description:"bla",value:234}]
    .reduce((arr, x) => {
      arr.values.push(x.value)
      arr.descriptions.push(x.description)
      return arr
    }, { values: [], descriptions: [] })

    console.log(data)
```

Comment: This is the only *correct* answer IMO. map requires 2 iterations and foreach is just *ugly*.

Comment: @Kinduser absolutely. Did you *understand* OP's question? Just because they used the word "remap" doesnt mean the needed the function `map`

Comment: @Jamiec "Ugly" is an opinion, though; it doesn't make forEach incorrect at all.

Comment: @Jamiec it also doesn't say anything about in-place modification. `reduce` here is clever and also pretty vile.

Comment: maping does not mean that you have to use map function

Comment: @Jamiec I've understood it this way that he expects two single arrays, which one contains all descriptions and the second one contains all values. And in this case, it's an object with two keys, which contains array. This result is actually far away from the desired output.

Comment: @pvg who said anything about in place modification? Are you misunderstanding what `reduce` does?

Comment: @Kinduser I don't see anything wrong with this approach, except that if the OP can't figure it out then this is likely a bit complex. Pulling out the two arrays is trivial, and this leads to a clean, functional approach.

Comment: @Jamiec This tosses `data` and replaces it with an object with two array properties. There's nothing in the question that suggests this, really.

Comment: @pvg IMO that's OK, though-answers should lead to an appropriate result, even if it's not precisely identical. In this case it's a trivial difference.

Comment: @DaveNewton He didn't mention anything about object containing arrays. It's just overwriting the OP question. And by the way - the fact that the method to reach the desired result is very trivial, is it a reason to downvote these answers?

Comment: @DaveNewton non-destructive solutions seem both clearer and safer but matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: My solution is like this because it don't change data that was maped erlier

Comment: @pvg Exactly - **non-destructive**. But still some people rather to just DV it instead of providing constructive feedback.

Comment: @Kinduser No, he didn't-in this case I find the difference immaterial since getting those separate arrays is trivial. Regarding the downvoting-no clue about the motivations of those who downvoting-no, you'll have to ask them.

Comment: @pvg I thought it was obvious this answer used immediate data as an example. Variable names are a pretty easy change if the OP needs to do that. There's no "in-place modification" here; there's an anonymous array that's reduced over. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, it's not the greatest use of precise language, but it is (to me, quite pointlessly) destructive. The other thing I'm not super-fond of is the fact that the generality of `reduce` is unnecessary here and does poor job of expressing the _intent_. It's a swiss-army chainsaw for a butter-knife job. But, yeah.

Comment: @pvg It wouldn't be my approach either. But there's nothing destructive here-nothing is modified except the accumulator. I'm not clear on why you view a simple change to make the array a named reference as such a big deal, but meh.

Answer (score -1):

```
var arrDescription = [];
var arrValue = [];

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
   //get the value of name
   //push the name string in the array
   arrDescription.push(data[key]["description"]);
   arrValue.push(data[key]["value"]);
});
```

Comment: It's an array, why use keys?

Comment: Object.keys() also work on array. It returns the keys of the elements from the array. See the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: I know what it does, I'm asking why use it since you don't need to?

Comment: Its an option, one can use foreach or Object.keys(). Both will iterate through the array once.

Comment: There's a lot of options-I just fail to see any good reason to recommend this one, that's all.